# Help me find a sci-fi short story possibly called 'Save Point'?

Tags: story-identification, horror

I've been looking for this story for a number of years and it's driving me mad. I'm not sure if it's something I read, or something I wrote as a teen for a creative writing project in school. I must have read it in early 2000s but is likely from mid to late-90s. It would have been in a book of similar short stories, either horror or sci-fi. I am in the UK.

From what I can remember it is called 'Save Point' and it's about a man who has a wife and child and his life is going well, so he signs up to a company that lets him create a "save point". If he ever wants to restart his life again from this save point, he just has to ask the company to roll his life back.

So there's a car crash and I think his wife dies (possibly). So he goes to the company and asks to be put back to the save point. They do it, but the file is corrupted so things aren't right. His wife is an alcoholic and their kid has issues too.

I can't remember how it ends, but I think he attempts to go back to the save point numerous times and things get messier and messier.

Comment: Zero matches on ISFDB; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=Save+point&type=Fiction+Titles. Any ideas where you might have read it?

Comment: Well, if it's something you write yourself, might be difficult for us to find ;)

Comment: If you did write it, I’d like to read it!

Comment: Sounds like a good story - I second Ernest Friedman's comment. I'd like to read it too.

Comment: There is a movie that is vaguely similar in theme.  The protagonist has made a backup of his life and is now living in the sim world.  However the sim copy is somewhat damaged.  The female interest or perhaps two do not work out.  I think there was a car crash.  Protagonist spends a lot of time talking to psychiatrist while wearing a half face prosthetic. (I hope I have not mixed up two movies).

Answer (score 7):

The Story is called **Save As** By **Michael Marshal Smith** in his collection of short stories **What you make it** published in 1999.

Man leaves hospital after a tragedy and goes to an organisation called "Same Again" where an illegal procedure is carried out and he is injected with something.

He wakes up to what appears to be a perfect suburban life that slowly disintegrates before him. It is slowly revealed that the backup is corrupted.

It is implied rather than stated that he restores more than once.